# TeX capacity exceeded: Beamer not working

Tags: beamer, xetex, capacity

I am trying to compile my beamer but somehow this line shows up and the file is not working:

TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]

Does anyone know what exactly happened? Thanks in advance!

My beamer file: https://www.overleaf.com/read/bpgddcswkthr

Answer (score 1):

This MWE made from your document will compile OK.

[image: A]

The main problem encountered (in this code) was the use of `\exe` instead of `\ex`. Maybe it is the only cause of the error you got.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {\usetheme{CambridgeUS}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
 \usepackage{kotex}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}

 \usepackage{gb4e} 

\title[XXXXXX]{XXXXXXXX} 

\author{XXXXXXX} 
\institute[HKUST] 
{
XXXXXXX \\ 
\medskip
\textit{XXXXXXXX} 
}
\date{19/09/2021} 


%-----------------First Page & Roadmap-------------------%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage 
    \vfill
    \textbf{xxxxxx\\xxxxxxxx}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{目錄}
    \tableofcontents 
\end{frame}

%%---------------------------------------------------------%
\section{簡介}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{「xxxxxxxx}
    xxxxxxxxxx\\
    \begin{itemize}
    \item x
    \item x
    \item x
    \end{itemize}

x

\begin{exe}
    \ex x %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \glt x
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
    \ex x %changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \glt x
\end{exe}
    
\end{frame}

%----------------------------References------------------%

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{References}
\footnotesize{
\begin{thebibliography}{99} % Beamer does not support BibTeX so references must be inserted manually as below
\bibitem[Smith, 2012]{p1} John Smith (2012)
\newblock Title of the publication
\newblock \emph{Journal Name} 12(3), 45 -- 678.
\end{thebibliography}
}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: To explain: the environment `exe` defines the two commands `\exe` and `\endexe`.  Trying to use those commands outside of the environment will cause all sorts of strange problems.

Comment: @Teepeemm The OP was using `\exe` inside the `exe` enviroment.

Comment: Thank everyone for your help!  I will try to compile it again with all the changes!